# Create regex pattern to match multiple whole words

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, word-boundary

I was trying to use this but unable to understand what is wrong here

```
preg_match('/\b'.$string.'\b/i', $fullstring);
```

The intention is to match a whole word only where the word is someone's input  which will be part of variable `$string`. E.g., "my name is alto better" which is separated by ' | ' to act as OR in regex operation.

```
<?php

$fullstring = 'Palo Alto New york colombia europe today Tomorrrow';
$string = 'my|name|is|alto|better';
preg_match('/\b'.preg_quote($string).'\b/i', $fullstring, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Output is *null*. What could be wrong?

Comment: What do sample `$value['user_id']` values look like?

Comment: it is something like "ABC1000"

Comment: And what is your `$string` like? I ask this because `\b` meaning is contextualy dependent.

Comment: $string is equal to "ABC1000",  "ABC1001"  etc

Comment: the requirement is - unless the full string matches the remaining steps will not be executed. But, somehow with \b and Preg_quote it is not working whereas without them (\b and preg_quote) we are getting result but then the result is not precise whichever matches "ABC1000" fully or partially is being returned. For example an user_id with value "ABC100010" also returned in result, which needs to be avoided

Comment: Sorry, it does not help understanding the issue. The search phrase is alphanumeric, preg_quote is not necessary in this case and a word boundary must work. I suggest you prepare a fiddle with sample data to repro the problem. Use any sites like ideone.com or reol.it or any other.

Comment: I have changed the example and also seen the output after executing the code. the output is null. can u suggest?

Comment: If your input is a regular expression with alternative branches you need to apply the word boundaries to a group, like `preg_match('/\b(?:' . $string . ')\b/i', $fullstring, $match);`

Comment: Wiktor is correct. And as he shows, the `preg_quote()` should NOT be applied to the regex $string - otherwise the "|" OR regex operators within $string will be escaped and lose their metacharacterishness.

Comment: Thank you @wiktor it worked as per expectation

Comment: @team I added an answer.

Comment: @team Please consider accepting the answer since it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a regular expression with alternative branches you need to apply the word boundaries to a group, see

```
 preg_match('/\b(?:' . $string . ')\b/i', $fullstring, $match);
```

Why use a grouping construct? Because if you just add word boundaries to the 
`'my|name|is|alto|better'` regex pattern, only `my` and `better` will be restricted in part: `my` will only match at the beginning of a word and `better` will match at the end of a word - that is in short the essence of the issue you had after adding word boundaries without grouping the alternatives first.